# Why is Blender rendering the wrong resolution?

Tags: rendering, video

I configured the output for 1080x1920, but it's rendering 1822x1922, so I can't append the video intro to the videos using Avidemux (Avidemux requires the videos to be of the same resolution). Why is this happening to me? How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to use a different Codec. Are single images rendered correctly? (F12)

Comment: I tried using "JPEG Avi". It says "resolution: 1088x1920" and "show resoluyion: 1080x1920". I could not understand what F12 did, I saw no new image file.

Comment: You need to change the render type to image to have one saved or when you have this single image not being rendered in background you can save it manually after having it displayed. It should be displayed after hitting F12.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the dial below the resolution fields is at 100%.

[image]

Comment: Also check your aspect ratio to X=1:Y=1 , it's just below the resolution number field shown on the image above.

Comment: It is. But when I render the video, open in VLC and show information about the media, it says:
*resolution: 1088x1922
*show resolution: 1080x1920

Comment: VLC might be at fault. I'm seeing exactly the same resolution as Anders, but another video player, djv_view reports 1080x1920